# Python3: Access a static function from a child class

Tags: python, parent-child, static-methods

How do I access a static function from a child class.

```
class Parent:
  bar = []

  @classmethod
  def foo(cls):
    print(' | '.join(cls.bar))

class Child_A(Parent):
  bar = ['abs', 'arq', 'agf']
  foo()  # ERROR: NameError: name 'foo' is not defined
### abs | arq | agf

class Child_B(Parent):
  bar = ['baz', 'bux', 'bet']
  foo()  # ERROR: NameError: name 'foo' is not defined

### baz | bux | bet

class Child_C(Parent):
  bar = ['cat', 'cqy', 'cos']
  foo()  # ERROR: NameError: name 'foo' is not defined

### cat | cqy | cos
```

The children each have their own set of `bar` lists and I want them to use the `foo()` function from the parent class to print out the correct string.

Comment: You have a class method.  Just use the parent object without instantiation. `Parent.foo()`

Comment: `Parent.foo()` returns the `Parent.bar`, not the `Child.bar`.

Comment: If that is what you want please explain it in your question, completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Parent:
    bar = []
    @classmethod
    def foo(cls):
        print(' | '.join(cls.bar))

class Child(Parent):
    bar = ['baz', 'qux', 'far']
Child.foo()
```

class method is a method that is bound to a class rather than its object. It doesn't require creation of a class instance. Classmethod will always return instance of same class not child class. Actually classmethod will break the rules of OOP's.

Answer (score 1):

Class methods are accessed using class names

so in your child class foo method is inherited but you have to call it with class name

```
class Parent:
    bar = []
    @classmethod
    def foo(cls):
        print(' | '.join(cls.bar))

class Child(Parent):
    bar = ['baz', 'qux', 'far']
    Child.foo()  # This will make cls Child class and access child's bar element
### baz | qux | far
```

Comment: I tried that. I get a different error saying `NameError: name 'Child' is not defined`